# Url rerouting after making an entry Django admin add page

Tags: django, django-templates, django-rest-framework, django-views, django-admin

After making an entry in django admin, django routes directly to entries page. What I want is to go to main admin page. Do I need to overwrite the admin views file or is there a way to extend it and change the url routing?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can override the `response_add()` method (or `response_change()` for editing existing entries) inside your [`ModelAdmin` class](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/admin/#modeladmin-objects) as follow:

```
def response_add(self, request, obj, post_url_continue=None):
    return redirect('/admin') # Or whatever URL you want
```